# Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod'

Tags: r

I have recently installed R 4.1 and when the software is started I see this:

[image]

Do you know what should I do? Or what does it mean?

Thank you

Comment: Check your home directory for a file named `.RData`. (No, this is not an extension, it's the full filename.) If it exists, remove it. You probably loaded package quantmod in a previous session and saved the session on exit so now when you start R it loads that session from `.RData`.

Comment: There is also close use of zoo objects in quantmod timeseries, viz [where the message comes from](https://rdrr.io/cran/quantmod/src/R/quantmod.R), suggesting use as.zoo. Why it is happening when you first start is likely due to @RuiBarradas comment.

Comment: I have removed it from my directory: "C:/Users/HP/Documents" However, it is still appearing.

Comment: Do you also have a `.Rprofile` file in your home directory? Or have you defined any other `?Startup` scripts that automatically load packages when you start R?

Comment: The issue is always when I start R, however, any of these packages are loaded. I am not sure if it has any other impact, however, it bothers me when I start R.

Comment: For me, it would be only enough if I can suppress this warning message.

Comment: The packages are already there when I start R I ran this function immediately when R started: dput(loadedNamespaces())
It says c("knitr", "magrittr", "grDevices", "tidyselect", "lattice", 
"R6", "rlang", "fansi", "TTR", "dplyr", "tools", "xts", "utils", 
"quantmod", "grid", "xfun", "utf8", "DBI", "htmltools", "stats", 
"shinyjs", "ellipsis", "datasets", "yaml", "digest", "assertthat", 
"tibble", "base", "lifecycle", "crayon", "purrr", "graphics", 
"vctrs", "curl", "rsconnect", "evaluate", "glue", "rmarkdown", 
"stringi", "zoo") I have not activated this packages.